# Bayesian statistics and Basis for continous functions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, integration, probability-distributions, bayesian

I was thinking about Bayesian statistics, and one thought bothered me:

In Bayesian statistics, we assume that the [pdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $p(x)$ can be described as:

\begin{equation}
p(x)=\int f(x|\theta)g(\theta)d\theta
\end{equation}

usually when $x\in[l,u]$, people choose $f$ to be [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)
\begin{equation}
p(x)=\int_l^u f(x|\alpha,\beta)g(\alpha)h(\beta) d\alpha d\beta
\end{equation}

(where $1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h$ and $h,g\geq 0$)

After that short intro, My question is:

**Can we model any continuous function like that ?**

In other words:

If $p: [l,u]\longrightarrow[0,1]$ is a continuous function, 
does that mean that we can find two functions $g,h$ such that
\begin{equation}
p(x)=\int_l^x f(x|\alpha,\beta)g(\alpha)h(\beta)d\alpha d\beta
\end{equation}

Comment: You're missing bits in your integrals! Like $d\theta, d\alpha, \dots$

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the functions $g, h$ you want to find? e.g. Must they be continuous, can they only be measurable/$L^1$? This is easier to answer in a measure theory setting.

Comment: Just  $1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h$ and $h,g\geq 0$

Comment: Question should be tidied up a bit. Why $g(\alpha)h(\beta)$ instead of $g(\alpha,\beta)$? This is most likely the main limitation in expressing $p$ from $f$. And the limit $\int_l^x$ makes no sense with $d\alpha\,d\beta$. Also, why should $p\le1$?

Comment: $p()$ is a pdf, therefore $0\leq p \leq 1$. If we model p as $p=\int{f(x|\alpha,\beta)g(\alpha,\beta)}$ does that guarantee the existence of such model ?

Comment: No, a probability density, $p(x)$, is not limited to $p\le1$. Just think of a normal distribution with small $\sigma$.

Comment: @UriGoren, the pdf need not be less than one. pdf need to be non-negative and integrate to $1$ over the interval of interest.

Also important context for the Bayesian interpretation: is $p$ supposed to be the prior or the posterior distriubution?

Comment: you are both right regarding the upper bound constraints, $p$ is the posterior distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, The representation
$p(x)=\int{f(x|\alpha,\beta)g(\alpha)h(\beta)}$
can span the entire $[l,u]$ segement if $g()$ and $h()$ are allowed to be negative.

This can be seen by extending polynomial approximation.

However, if $h,g \geq 0$, the answer is simply no.

$p(x)\equiv 1$ cannot be obtained

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the case of the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha,\beta>0$:
$$
f(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
\quad\text{where}\quad
B(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
The question is if a continuous probability distribution $p(x)$ on $[0,1]$ can always be expressed in terms of $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ with weights $g(\alpha)\cdot h(\beta)$.

There are two problems. The first is if $p(x)$ can be expressed as a combination of $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ terms at all, i.e. with weights $q(\alpha,\beta)$. The other is if these weights can be split as $g(\alpha)\cdot h(\beta)$.

If $p(x)$ has a zero for some $x\in(0,1)$, e.g. $p(1/2)=0$, then obviously it cannot be expressed as a combination of $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ as these are all strictly positive on $(0,1)$. Of course, if we require $p(x)>0$, this limitation is avoided, but I suspect there will still be limitations on how small $p(x)$ can be for particular $x$.

The other problem is in terms of splitting the weights as $g(\alpha)\cdot h(\beta)$. I asked about this in a comment since it is a rather different problem, and I wasn't sure if this was really what you were interested in. However, my suspicion is that there will be cases, e.g. on the form
$p(x)=[f(x;n,1)+f(x;1,n)]/2$, for which this splitting cannot be done using non-negative coefficients, but have no proof of this.

Comment: Take a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306891/are-gaussians-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-continuous-functions), Gaussians are a basis for the vector space, can we say the same on the beta functions ?

Comment: @UriGoren: As a vector space basis, there should be no problem: a continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be arbitrarily well approximated by polynomials. However, you require non-negative coefficients.