# Are Gaussians a basis for the vector space of continuous functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, normal-distribution, infinitesimals

How can I prove (or disprove) that the Gaussian function family:

$f_{\mu,\sigma}(x)=e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$

Are a basis for $C(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: Clearly they are not an _algebraic_ basis (the constant function $1$ is not a finite linear combination of Gaussians). If you want to allow infinite sums, then which notion of convergence are you using?

Comment: Isn't the constant function a gaussian with parameter $\sigma=\infty$

Comment: @Uri Goren  They will form even more than a basis.  Check out the Weierstrass transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform that uses a subset of these.  It points out in there that: "Weierstrass used this transform in his original proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem."

Comment: @muaddib, thank you !